# How Do I Auto Adjust the Screen Calibration on an ASUS monitor?

Tags: display

I'm trying to help a remote user who has an Asus VH196T-P monitor. Part of her screen is cutoff even though the resolution is set properly.

Typically this is an extremely simple problem to solve as you simply hit the "Auto" button on most monitors and it will recalibrate itself and display things on the monitor correctly. However, it appears that Asus monitors (or at least this one) do not have that "Auto" button.

I've tried to have her go through the different menu options with me on the phone but I haven't been able to pinpoint where exactly this option is.

Can one of you out there with an Asus monitor please help me out? I've spent too much time on what should be a ridiculously simple problem (and would be if it wasn't remote).

Comment: Could you not fully power off the monitor and then turn back on and it should auto adjust the screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this issue previously and there was a trick on the Asus website

- Press [MENU] key to enter OSD menu,
  then scroll to [System Setup] page
  and select [Reset] to restore default
  setting
- Press [SPLENDID] key for 4~5 seconds to auto adjust the monitor setting
- You can also enter OSD menu > [Image] > [Position] to adjust the vertical and horizontal position of the image

Comment: Going to check and see but I'm guessing this will do the trick...will award the answer once verified. Thanks!